# Joomla Questionnaire Component Customization?

Tags: joomla, components, customization, recommendation-engine, custom-component

i developed a lawyer website and looking the below mentioned:

I have 5 categories and each category have 40 questions(in 4 pages with/without mandatory options).all the questions are managed by admin only and the questions have checkbox,dropdown,radio button and so on.

i searched for component in joomla 1.5,1.6,1.7 but i failed.no component can be found.any one help me to get rid of this problem.

Please Recommend any component.

---

**Example:**

*Categories:*

LLC (Limited Liability Company),

DBA/Business Names

Non-Profit

Partnership Agreements

Business Licenses

Bylaws & Resolutions

Certificate of Good Standing

Certified Copies

Compliance Calendar

Conversion

Corporate Minutes

Corporate Supplies

Entity Name Availability Check

Entity Name Reservation

---

These are the categories and each category have 40 questions in 10 pages.Each page have 4 questions.client(User) must answer these questions before make payment.i need to summary the answers typed by client(user).

Each category have different 40 questions.

please help me.am new to joomla.

Thanks in advance.

---

**EDIT:**

Multi-Form Submit with progressbar component for free.please recommend this.

Comment: Machan come to Casual Chat da..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using [ChronoForms 4](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/forms/1508) for simple questionnaire and it's very powerful, as not so user-friedly in admin configuration. The best feature is that you can customize every action on form showing and on form submitting. However I thik it's a bit hard to create a multipage form with this, but maybe in the [forum](http://www.chronoengine.com/forums/) some may answer, they reply very quicly.